# Firestore Timestamp to ArrayList<String> and then to Date

Tags: java, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I have a static ArrayList being populated at startup from Firebase to store a variety of values. One of the FB fields I need to store is a Timestamp.

I need to store the Timestamp in my array, but then display it later in a readable Date format.

Initialise the ArrayList:

```
static ArrayList<String> suspectedValues = new ArrayList();
```

Get the timestamp from FB:

```
Timestamp dtg = (Timestamp) document.getData().get("dtg");
```

Set the timestamp as a String and store in the Array:

```
String timeStamp = String.valueOf(dtg);
String suspectedData [] = {timeStamp};
suspectedValues.addAll(Arrays.asList(suspectedData));
```

Later in a different activity onCreate:

```
int counter = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < suspectedValues.size(); i = i + 4){

    String timeStamp = suspectedValues.get(4);
    Date dtg = new Date(Long.parseLong(timeStamp));

    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(suspected).snippet("id: " + id + " | " + taggedAt + ": " + dtg).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

    if(suspectedValues.size() != 0){
        counter = counter + 4;
    }
}
```

I have tried a number of different conversions between Timestamp, Date and String but cant get this to work. When I try to set the Date dtg I get:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "56.504800874303676"
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:594)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:636)
```

I have also tried:

```
Timestamp dtg = (Timestamp) document.getData().get("dtg");
Date date = dtg.toDate();
String timeStamp = date.toString();
String suspectedData [] = {timeStamp};
suspectedValues.addAll(Arrays.asList(suspectedData));
```

with:

```
String timeStamp = suspectedValues.get(4);
Date theSameDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(timeStamp);
```

But it keeps throwing a Parse exception.

```
Timestamp from FB: Timestamp(seconds=1583706187, nanoseconds=895000000)
Converted to Date: Sun Mar 08 22:23:07 GMT 2020
timestamp String going into Array: Sun Mar 08 22:23:07 GMT 2020
timestamp String coming out of Array: 62.76105524614817
I/MapsActivity: ParseException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "62.76105524614817"
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Firebase outputs a Timestamp so I have to use it...I think...

Comment: From: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-cloud-firestore/understanding-date-in-firestore/
"Firestore use Timestamp class to represent DateTime on the client (Android), and it does not store TimeZone information.
There is convenient Timestamp method to work with Java Date: Date toDate() and Timestamp(Date date).
There is no convenient Timestamp method to work with Java Time or threetenbp or ThreeTenABP."

Comment: That’s unfortunate. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @OleV.V. For clarity - the Firestore Timestamp is a server generated Timestamp not a locally generated one. It's a much more secure option as locally (device level) timestamps can be altered whereas server generated ones are guaranteed to be accurate since they come from the server, not the device. OP: You don't *have* to use the Firestore Timestamp but for use cases where the timestamp needs to be accurate, then it's a safe bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured a workaround,

I created two separate ArrayLists, one accepts String and the 2nd accepts Date.

```
static ArrayList<String> suspectedValues = new ArrayList();
static ArrayList<Date> suspectedDateValues = new ArrayList<>();
```

I put all my Dates in the 2nd ArrayList instead of the 1st.

I also created 2 counters.

```
int counter = 0;
int counter1 = 0;
```

I know that I have a date after every 3 values in the first ArrayList. So as I iterate through the 1st list, I call a new method, passing in all the values from the 1st method, which retrieves the date from the 2nd ArrayList and uses the date alongside the passed values to execute my tasks.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < suspectedValues.size(); i = i + 3){

        [snip]

        getSuspectedDate(lat, lng, gMap, counter1, passedActivity, id, smallMarker);

        if(suspectedValues.size() != 0){
            counter = counter + 3;
            counter1 = counter1 + 1;
        }
    }
```

And my final method executed on each iteration of the `for` loop above:

```
public void getSuspectedDate(double lat, double lng, GoogleMap gMap, int counter1, Activity passedActivity, String id, Bitmap smallMarker){
        String suspected = passedActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.suspected);
        String taggedAt = passedActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.taggedDTG);

            Date date = suspectedDateValues.get(counter1);
            String dtg = String.valueOf(date);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(suspected).snippet("id: " + id + " | " + taggedAt + ": " + dtg).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));

        }
```

Not the cleanest solution, but it works!